# using Javascript to link pages from subdomain to another subdomain with same structure subfolder

Tags: javascript, http, hyperlink

I am trying to creat a button that will link a subdomain but keep the same path for the page.

clicked it goes from

sub1.maindomain.com/folder01/folder02/folder03/

to

sub2.maindomain.com/folder01/folder02/folder03/

I would like to script it, I want it be added to the site template.

Kinda rusted with my JS.

Thank you if you can give me pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `location` object.

```
var path = location.pathname; //pathname will return the complete path of the uri without the host/domain.
var queryString = location.search.length > 0 ? location.search : ""; //this will retrieve the querystring if available.
var newLink = "sub2.maindomain.com" + path + queryString;

document.getElementById("link").href = newLink; //replace [link] with an id from your anchor element/button element.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var loc=window.location.href;
var path=loc.substring(19);//flesh this out to be smarter for your use case
var newdomain = "sub2.maindomain.com";

var link=jQuery("#linkid").attr('href',newdomain+path);
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.